# Reuse component in projection (NHibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, components, dto, projection

Is it possible to reuse a component mapping in a projection?

Here is the mapping for the Vendor entity:

```
   <class name="Vendor" table="vendor">
     ...
     <property name="Name" column="Name" />
     <component name="Address" class="MyProject.Address, MyAssembly" >
       <property name="Street" column="street" />
       <property name="City" column="City" />
     </component>
   </class>
```

For a report I'd like to retrieve these vendors in a data transfer object but reuse the Address component (because there are many fields and some useful formatting behavour).

```
public class VendorDTO
{
    public string Name;
    public Address Address;

}

public class Address
{
    public string Street;
    public string City;
    public string SomeUsefulBehavour();
}
```

Is this possible without splitting Address out into it's own table?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a query? What do you mean by "reuse a component mapping in a projection"? I don't understand the question...

Comment: Possible hints - you can write your own ResultTranslators; you can try using HQL construct new Address(); I haven't tried either of them, so just hints.

Comment: Yes I was hoping for a query similar to:
  select new VendorDTO(vendor.Name, vendor.Address)
  from Vendor vendor
Thanks for the hints.

Comment: select new VendorDTO(vendor.Name, vendor.Address) does not work?

Comment: I think you should be able to achieve this using AliasToBeanResultTransformer

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should 'just work':

```
Session.QueryOver<Vendor>()
    .SelectList(builder =>
        builder.Select(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x => x.Address))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<VendorDTO>())
    .List<VendorDTO>();
```